# Pygame Import error:No module named py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, importerror

I am trying to make a mobile app in which you can go to calculator with pygame. What I am trying to do is when you click the calculator image, it opens calculator app and then when you press the home button , it goes back to home.

**Problem:** But then , if you are at home page after opening the calculator app , and then you try to again go to the calculator app it gives me an error:

> ImportError: No module named py

But this error should not come since I already have the pygame module.

## Code saved as 'mytake.py'

```
import pygame

#Loading Images
img = pygame.image.load('main1.png')
img2= pygame.image.load('calcu.png')
img15=pygame.image.load('HOME2.png')

#Setting Screen size
w = 600
h = 450

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w, h])
x = y = 0
running = True

pygame.init()

WHITE=(255,255,255)

#Running loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))

    B=screen.blit(img2,(37,305))
    N=screen.blit(img15,(94,355))
    pygame.display.update()



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            #mixer.music.play(0)
            X= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print "Click: ",X
            print X[0],X[1]

            #Open Calculator 
            if B.collidepoint(X[0],X[1]):
                import calc.py
```

## This is my calculator code saved as 'calc.py'

```
import time
import pygame

#Loading images
img15=pygame.image.load('HOME2.png')
img16=pygame.image.load('calcimg.png')

#Screen Size
w = 600
h = 450
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w, h])
x = y = 0
running = True

pygame.init()

WHITE=(255,255,255)
X= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
while running:


    screen.blit(img16,(0,0))
    N=screen.blit(img15,(94,359))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            X= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print "Click: ",X
            print X[0],X[1]


    #Go back to home page
    pygame.display.flip()
    if N.collidepoint(X[0],X[1]):
        import mytake.py
```

## Images used Images used (save according to given names):

[image: caclimg] 
Saved as caclimg
[image: calcu]
Saved as calcu
[image: HOME2]
Saved as HOME2
[image: main1]
Saved as main1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt to fix this.

```
import pygame, time, sys

img = pygame.image.load('main1.png')
img2= pygame.image.load('calcu.png')
img15=pygame.image.load('HOME2.png')
img16=pygame.image.load('calcimg.png')
w = 600
h = 450
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w, h])
x=y=0

pygame.init()
WHITE=(255,255,255)
location = 'home'
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            X= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print("Click: ",X)
            print(X[0],X[1])
            if B.collidepoint(X[0],X[1]):
                location = 'calc'
                print(location)
            elif N.collidepoint(X[0],X[1]):
                location = 'home'
                print(location)
    if location == 'home':
        screen.blit(img,(0,0))
        B=screen.blit(img2,(37,305))
        N=screen.blit(img15,(94,355))
    if location == 'calc':
        screen.blit(img16,(0,0))
        N=screen.blit(img15,(94,359))
    pygame.display.update()
```

This has nothing to do with `pygame`.

Simply, do not write `import sample.py` - use only `import sample`.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) for more information.

Comment: But then if i again click the calculator app image , it does not take me back to the home page it just print coordinates of mouse click.

Comment: @Krut Is it not giving the error any more? If so, then this question is answered.

Comment: But I want to go back to home page after i click the image.What I asked was this :
" What I am trying to do is when you click the calculator image, it opens calculator app and then when you press the home button , it goes back to home."

Comment: @Krut Okay, you have a big issue that I see now. `import`s are not meant to act as functions, so use a function instead. Just combine both files into one and use functions to switch the screen after setting up `pygame`. I have Python 3.5, not 2.7, so I will not want to or be able to do this for you, but I can try to guide you if you still encounter issues.

Comment: #StarDustGeogta , i have been trying to do that but cant understand how to make it as a function.

Comment: @Krut Do you at least understand the `def insert_thing_here:` syntax?

Comment: Yes i do @StardustGogeta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114065/discussion-between-stardustgogeta-and-krut-patel).